# How kotlin makes setOnClickListener accept functions as parameter

Tags: android, kotlin

In kotlin, we can use `setOnClickListener()` like this:

```
view.setOnClickListener { println("Hello") }
```

But if I define my own interface, I can only pass anonymous object like this:

```
obj.setMyListener(object: MyListener() {
    ...
})
```

I just wondering how they make `setOnClickListener()` accept a function rather than an anonymous object.

Comment: `MyListener` needs to have just one method. Otherwise you need to create an `object:MyListener`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to Kotlin documentations about [Java interop](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions), for a functional interface defined in Java, you can use a SAM conversion.

> Just like Java 8, Kotlin supports SAM conversions. This means that
>   Kotlin function literals can be automatically converted into
>   implementations of Java interfaces with a single non-default method,
>   as long as the parameter types of the interface method match the
>   parameter types of the Kotlin function.

```
val runnable = Runnable { println("This runs in a runnable") }

val executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
// Java signature: void execute(Runnable command)
executor.execute { println("This runs in a thread pool") }
```

However, Kotlin has functional types, therefore SAM conversion doesn't work for interfaces defined in Kotlin:

> Also note that this feature works only for Java interop; since Kotlin
>   has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into
>   implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore
>   unsupported.

---

### Possible solutions:

1. Define the interface in Java. Useful if it is a library/code that may be used from a Java code.
2. Make the method receive a function as argument:

   ```
   // Example listener receives a bool and return unit.  
   fun setMyListener(listener: (isChecked: Bool) -> Unit) { ... }  
   // Usage:  
   obj.setMyListener { isChecked -> }
   ```
3. Use type alias (only supported in Kotlin 1.1+):

   ```
   typealias MyListener = (Bool) -> Unit
   fun setMyListener(listener: MyListener) { ... }
   ```