# Kotlin anonim class implement interface

Tags: kotlin

My kotlin interface:

```
interface IRunnable<T> {
    fun doWork(): T
}
```

then i create anonymous class implemented my interface:

```
executor!!.execute(object : IRunnable<Long> {
    override fun doWork(): Long {
        return 0L
    }
})
```

if interface in java, code look like

```
 executor!!.execute(IRunnable2 { return@IRunnable2 0L })
```

Any ideas, how to implement interface in kotlin like java?

Comment: If you create an interface *in Java* and *with one method* you can use the shortcut in Kotlin. That's it. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions If you define an interface *in Kotlin* you have to extend the interface. The shortest way is to define the interface in Java and move on.

Answer (score 2):

please, don't use `IRunnable` such naming in kotlin.

As in this question [How kotlin makes setOnClickListener accept functions as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180365/how-kotlin-makes-setonclicklistener-accept-functions-as-parameter) described, Kotlin do SAM only for Java interfaces. But, you can change Interface in favor of functional type, or implement interface, and use it as in following example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    class Executor {
        fun <T> execute(task: SimpleRunnable<T>): CompletableFuture<T> {
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {
                task.doWork()
            }
        }
    }

    val executor = Executor()

    executor.execute(SimpleRunnableImpl { "42" })

    executor.execute(object : SimpleRunnable<Long> {
        override fun doWork(): Long {
            return 0L
        }
    })
}

interface SimpleRunnable<T> {
    fun doWork(): T
}

class SimpleRunnableImpl<T>(val task: () -> T) : SimpleRunnable<T> {
    override fun doWork(): T = task()
}
```